# how to create a user in mysql 5.1 with all permissions?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a user with permission to create database, import mysqldump files, create tables?

What is the command for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: in the MySQL client, run the following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to username@hostname_or_ip identified by 'password';
```

Longer answer:

There is really excellent documentation in the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1-maria/en/index.html) on this topic. Take special note of the [chapter on User Account Management](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1-maria/en/user-account-management.html).

Comment: I should add that this query should be executed from the "root" account: the one that has "WITH GRANT OPTION" privilege

Answer (score 1):

GRANT ALL 
ON *.*
TO *username*@"%"
IDENTIFIED BY "*password*";